# Изменить flex-order при переносе на новую строку без @media

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Есть следующий лайаут:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <button class="back">←</button>
  <div class="container">
    page content
  </div>
  <button class="close">×</button>

</div>
```

мне нужно именно при переносе элементов внутри div.page изменить порядок на такой:

```
.back {
  order: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.close {
  order: 1
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container {
  order: 2;
}
```

Вопрос: возможно ли это без JS, только на чистом CSS;
@media не решит вопрос т.к. контейнер может быть разной ширины, может также быть левое меню (свёрнутое или развернутое)

с JS я вижу 2 выхода:

1. положить кнопки в position: fixed и с помощью intersectionObserver ловить пересечения, добавлять margin-top для div.container;
2. создать header.page__header, также position: fixed и на ресайз страницы смотреть размеры и добавлять margin-top для div.container;

Вот такой результат мне нужен, когда происходит перенос внутри page
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы решить этот кейс красиво на чистом CSS. Если кто знает решение — подскажите, пожалуйста.